# Trying to Load object with ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need help loading a object file from my local browser in Threejs ( Rev 71). The error I get is loadModel.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token #.

I tried loading the object file by chrome --allow-file-access-from-files, but 
still I get a blank page with the same error. I Would like to know what I did wrong within this simple script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Load Model</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">

<script src="three.js"></script>
<script src="ObjectLoader.js"></script>

<script>
    var scene, camera, renderer;
    init();
    animate();
    function init()
    {
        scene = new THREE.Scene()
        var WIDTH   = window.innerWidth,
            HEIGHT  = window.innderHeight;

        //Created camera
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH/HEIGHT, 0.1, 2000);
        camera.position.set(0,0, 100);
        scene.add(camera);

        var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
        scene.add(ambientLight);

        var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
        loader.load( 'obj/Male.obj', function (object) {
            scene.add( object );
        });

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
        renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


    }

    function animate()
    {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are reported in the console?

Comment: need more details...  which version you are using... console errors?

Comment: I created a scene with the same revision of three.js and OBJLoader and had the same issue, I used your  code. I think your using is out-dated for the OBJloader... Try ObjectMTL as this worked for me with no problems also i think you may need matarial added to your objloader could be a cause

Comment: Be careful not to confuse ObjectLoader and OBJLoader.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, but then I checked carefully the object file, and there were the values like **".#IND"** ("IND" for "indeterminate") in some arrays, which was generated by some script while converting the object from one file to another ("#" caused that error), I changed these values to "0", and the issue "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token #" disappeared like a fine mist in the morning.